# Change AdMob Banner style to Custom

Tags: android, ios, admob, customization

I changed the AdMob style to custom.

Then, I set background, border, title and text colours. But, banner style didn't change in my app device.

What could be the problem.

**Note** I am pretty sure that I had the correct code and settings to do that.

Comment: the code was the admob basic code. didnt feel that I had to include it because "it doesnt concern problem with code" i discribed the problem it's not with code. banner styling have nothin to do with code. l also included a note!

Comment: is this question closed. i really see that question and answer have valuable information. note to ppl that dont know. banner styling does not include code you do it in their site. thats y my question has no code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after customising ads banner it took some time to be applied. :)

Also, as an experience AdMob is not always applying your custom style to the banners. Some times the default style is applied!

You could have some Ads in your style and another one with the default style. All that at the same run of the app., same activity and same banner.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: I don't know what they didnt like about the answer. it is the correct answer!!!\

Comment: this is a complete answer!!!!

Comment: Sounds like @hasan is simply answering his own question, in that after customization, the changes *were* indeed applied, but only after a time delay. Maybe not worded very clearly, but seems like he figured it out. Not sure why he's being called out as saying *thank you* in an answer, unless that was there before and someone deleted it...

Comment: that wasnt there before.

Comment: @david The answer just has a misspelled "some time" as content. It could be improved with links to documentation, how much time, why you have to wait, ... If lots of people are misunderstanding then it might have something to do with the "answer".

Comment: @dcaswell ok, good points, answer can be beefed up as you stated. My original comment was really questioning the initial comment under the answer, which seemed out of place (possibly posted to the wrong answer?)